# Получить id woocommerce-категории текущего товара

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

Вообщем есть товар, допустим красная сумка. И у него имеется такой порядок вложенности категорий: Женская одежда -> Сумки -> Товар красная сумка. Весь магазин работает на основе woocommerce, и категории так же добавлены через него. 
**Нужно получить id категории текущего товара при помощи php.** Допустим, в примере с красной сумкой (Женская одежда -> Сумки -> Товар красная сумка) нужно сразу получить id категории "Сумки". Я уже почти решил эту задачу следующим кодом:

`global $post;`

`$terms = get_the_terms( $post->ID, 'product_cat' );`

`foreach ($terms as $term) {`

`$product_cat_id = $term->term_id;`

`echo $product_cat_id;`

    `break;`

`}`

Но этот код возвращал id категории родителя, а нужно id потомка.(В примере с красными сумками: *Женская одежда -> Сумки -> Товар красная сумка* - код возвращал id категории "Женская одежа", а нужно, чтобы код вернул id категории Сумки, или ближе всего находящийся категории. Т.е Если есть цепочка из 5 категорий, то нужно вернуть id самой последней, в которой находится товар)
*Заранее спасибо за помощь.*

Comment: https://wp-kama.ru/function/get_term_children

Comment: Получите id категории в которой лежит товар через ‘get_the_terms()’ и ваша задача решена, тем более у вас в примере уже есть этот код

Comment: Ответ, приведенный выше, не подходит. Вопрос к автору, удалось ли в итоге найти решение? Столкнулся с той же самой проблемой - получаю id категории родителя, а не самой текущей категории товаров...

Answer (score 0):

Для получения верхнего родителя есть функция get_top_term()

```
$terms = wp_get_post_terms( $product->ID, 'product_cat', $args );
$top_term = get_top_term( $terms[0]->term_id );
```